# Wordpress :Load a static page before site loads

Tags: php, html, wordpress, .htaccess

i have developed  2 WordPress sites that are registered against same domain with bit of difference . Now for example my domain  is `www.xyz.com` and  `first site is xyz/1  and second site is xyz/2`.In WordPress what i want to show a static page that shwos 2 links  xyz/1 and xyz/2 and users clicks and goes to specific site .How do i set up that page for WordPress site ?

Comment: Why don't you just keep both your Wordpress sites in their two respective directories, and then just create a static HTML file, and place it in your root and name it index.html?

Comment: How did you get on with this Sikander?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this without having to do anything special inside Wordpress.

So you've got two Wordpress sites in two subdirectories, that you want to be accessible via clicking the relevant link on the homepage of your root domain?

You can just create your own tailored HTML file, name it index.html and place it at the root of your site. Include your links to each site, for the user to view.

Answer (score 1):

in the control panel there is an option for static landing page, can't remember which tab but it is there, let's say index.php, on that page create your 2 links. [http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-setting-static-front-pages-in-wordpress--wp-34527.](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-setting-static-front-pages-in-wordpress--wp-34527)